# $$ literal quoting and hexadecimal literals

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#dollar-quoted-string-constants) shows literals may be delineated with $$ rather than quotes, e.g. when the string contains quotes.  The example in the documentation includes a hexadecimal literal.

However, when used in a TRANSLATE function, it appears the \x escape for hexadecimal literals is ignored and the individual letters are being considered instead.  The SELECT statement below illustrates the effect.  I'm using $$ because single and double quotes are also part of the "from" string in the TRANSLATE in my real code.

```
select translate('Costco',$$\xC2\xC0\xC3\xC4\xC8\xC9\xD4\xE0\xE1\xE2\xE3\xE4\xE8\xE9\xF4 $$,'AAAAEEOaaaaaeeo-') as dollar
,  translate('Costco','\xC2\xC0\xC3\xC4\xC8\xC9\xD4\xE0\xE1\xE2\xE3\xE4\xE8\xE9\xF4 ','AAAAEEOaaaaaeeo-') as quoted;
```

Answer (score 0):

following documentation:

```
A dollar-quoted string constant can include quotes, or any other character, without the need to escape them. The string content is always written literally. Note that the string constant cannot contain double-dollar signs.
```

you can't use hex chars in a dollar-quoted string because it will be treated literally (basically that disappearing C doesn't come from the fact it's skipping the first \x, but from the fact that your second string becomes to short, so you're telling it to translate C into nothing. If you replace any of those late Cs with a small o, that's going to disappear too)